Xpath for SVG Element
The webpage https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login has four links at the bottom-left for linkedin, facebook, twitter and youtube.
I am trying to click the elements using the following
//click the linkedin link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//[name()='svg']/[name()='g'])[position()='1']")).click();
which always throws the below
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: (//[name()='svg']/[name()='g'])[position()='1']

You have to use below xpath to click on facebook element. If you want to select any other link you have to change value as per href.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'facebook')]").click();

